# Protect and unprotect workbook structure

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to create a macro to Unprotect (so I can run some of my macros) and when the macro ran successfully protect the workbook structure + worksheets again, protecting the workbooksheets works fine until I added the (un)protect of the workbook structure, it is giving me error

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

and I do not understand why, anyone any ideas?

this is the code I am using to (un)protect

```
For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         wsheet.Unprotect (XYZ1!!), Structure:=False
Next wsheet

'----
 
For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         wsheet.Protect (XYZ1!), Structure:=True
Next wsheet
```

some advice/help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `XYZ1!` use `"XYZ1!"` :)

Comment: ^^^ strings in VBA should always be in quotes

Comment: @MaciejLos thanks for your reply but unfortunately this is not working

Comment: "this is not working " is not very precise, what, exactly happens now? You did keep the password in brackets? (ex: `wsheet.Unprotect ("XYZ1!!")` )

Comment: You’re right, not precise.. sorry, yet it gives me the exact same error… when I run the macro without “ , structure:= false” it’s works but then it doesn’t remove the workbook structure protection, that is my issue

Comment: `Structure` does not seem to be an available argument for the `Protect` method?

Comment: Structure is a parameter for [workbook.protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect) not worksheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Private Sub UnprotectAllSheets()
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
     For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         wsheet.Unprotect (XYZ123!)
      Next wsheet
End Sub

Private Sub ProtectAllSheets()
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
     For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         wsheet.Protect (XYZ123!)
      Next wsheet
End Sub

Private Sub protect_wb_structure()


    Dim wbPRotect As Workbook
    Const strPassword As String = "XYZ123!"
    Set wbPRotect = ThisWorkbook
    wbPRotect.Protect Password = strPassword, Structure = False, Window = False

End Sub

Private Sub Unprotect_wb_structure()


    Dim wbunprotect As Workbook
    Const strPassword As String = "XYZ123!"
    Set wbunprotect = ThisWorkbook
    wbunprotect.Protect Password = strPassword, Structure = True, Window = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Unprotecting Workbook and Worksheets only accept 1 parameter which is the password string.

[Workbook Unprotect Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3qEt.png)

So your codes can be like this:

```
Sub UnprotectWorkbookWorksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Const strPassword As String = "XYZ1!!"
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    wb.Unprotect strPassword

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         ws.Unprotect strPassword         
    Next ws

End Sub
```

The Structure option is only available in the Protect method.

[Workbook Protect Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6MWB.png)

So your codes can look like this:

```
Sub ProtectWorkbookWorksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Const strPassword As String = "XYZ1!!"
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         ws.Protect strPassword
    Next ws

    wb.Protect Password = strPassword, Structure = True, Window = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to modify it slightly (see bellow) but now it is working fine!

Comment: @NewbieNils, that's great to hear!